# AD360 and Speedlight single controller for Nikon manual or TTL

Tags: lighting

I currently have a Flashpoint TTL-n ad360. I would like to remotely control it and perhaps 2 additional speedlights--I guess either Godox or Flashpoint brand--with a single trigger unit on-camera, both in TTL or manual remote control. Which speedlights do you recommend and is there a single trigger that can do all this? How about the new R2 Pro controller? Additionally have an SB700 and some Nissin di700 TTL Nikon flashes if they could me made to work with the Godox 360 and planned new speedlights. By the way, I am aware that Flashpoint is actually a private Godox brand. Does Godox also build Yongnuo?

Comment: Can you please ask the second question (about Godox branding) in a separate question? This site works best that way. Thanks!

Comment: "By the way" does not usually work well for the stack exchange format, which is *one* question per post. Normally I would suggest submitting you "by the way" as a separate question but I think in this case that would be such a poor question as to be a waste. No, Godox does not build Yongnuo, or vice versa.

Comment: Since I can find no reference to a product named "Flashpoint TTL-n ad360", my answer below assumes you mean the Flashpoint Streaklight 360 TTL for Nikon that is the equivalent to the Godox AD360II Nikon.

Answer (score 2):

Everything you ever wanted to know about the Godox/Flashpoint 2.4GHz RF Radio System [Part One](http://flashhavoc.com/godox-flash-system-overview/) and [Part 2](http://flashhavoc.com/godox-flash-and-trigger-models/).

Your Flashpoint Streaklight 360 TTL for Nikon (Godox AD360II) can be used as part of the Godox/Flashpoint 2.4GHz system. It has a built in 2.4GHz radio receiver that uses the Godox/Flashpoint protocol.  Any Godox/FP 2.4GHz trigger or any Godox/FP 2.4GHz "Master Flash" can control flashes that are part of the Godox/Flashpoint 2.4GHz radio system. This includes:

Controllers (those with an asterisk are Manual only, all others are TTL + Manual)

- X2T/R2 II TTL
- R2 Pro II
- XPro/R2 Pro
- X1T/R2 TTL
- XT32*/R2T 32*
- XT16*

Master flashes (those with an asterisk are Manual only, all others are TTL + Manual)

- TT350/Zoom-Mini R2 TTL
- V350/Zoom-Mini Li-Ion R2 TTL
- TT600/Zoom R2 Manual*
- V850II/Zoom Li-Ion R2 Manual*
- TT685/Zoom R2 TTL
- V860II/Zoom Li-Ion R2 TTL
- V1/Zoom Li-Ion X R2 TTL
- AD360II/Streaklight 360 R2 TTL

Note that TTL capable Controllers and Master flashes are brand specific (Nikon, Canon, etc.) when used on the brand specific camera (Nikon, Canon, etc.). This is due to the different patterns of the connection interface that each brand (Nikon, Canon, etc.) uses. However, the radios in Controllers and "Master Flashes" are cross-compatible with all off-camera flashes in the Godox/FP 2.4GHz system. That is, a "Nikon" AD360II can be controlled via radio by a "Canon" R2 Pro. Some brand specific (Nikon, Canon, etc.) TTL features may not be available when, for example, using a Nikon camera + controller with an off-camera Canon/Sony/Fuji flash. But all manual features should be available with all combinations of Godox/FP 2.4GHz Controllers/"Master Flashes" and Godox/FP off camera flashes.

In addition to the "Master Flashes" listed above, the following flashes can also be used as radio controlled off camera "slaves" with the Godox 2.4GHz system. The 'Speedlights' have built-in radio receivers, as do the other units listed below (Manual only flashes marked with an asterisk):

- AD200/Evolv 200 R2 TTL
- AD200 Pro/Evolv 200 Pro TTL
- AD400 Pro/Xplor 400 Pro R2 TTL
- AD600BM*/Xplor 600 R2 HSS*
- AD600B/Xplor 600 R2 TTL HSS
- AD600 Pro/Xplor 600 Pro
- ADH600B*/ADH1200B*/Xplor 600ws Extension Head*/Xplor 1200ws Extension Head*
- QT400II-M*/QT600II-M*/QT800II-M*/Rapid 600 R2 HSS*
- QT1200II-M*
- QS400II*/QS600II*/QS800II*
- QS1200II*
- SK300II*/SK400II*/Studio 300 R2*/Studio 400 R2*
- DP300II*/DP400II*/DP600II*/DP800II*/DP1000II*
- DS300II*/DS400II*
- GS200II*/GS300II*/GS400II*

There are older "legacy" Godox/Flashpoint flashes that can be used in the 2.4GHz system with clip-on receivers. These older flashes are all manual only when used with the following clip on receivers:

- XTR-16 (for bare bulb and studio strobes)
- XTR-16s (for speedlights)

To use other non-Godox/Flashpoint off-camera flashes, such as your SB700 and Nissin Di700 TTL flashes, with the Godox system you would need to attach a Godox X1R 2.4GHz receiver to the hot foot of the flash. If the flash is TTL capable, then using the appropriate version (Nikon, Canon, etc.) of the X1R receiver would allow the flash to be used as a TTL flash.

- X1R

Comment: @inkista Aren't some of those AC strobes you added asterisks to TTL capable?

Comment: None of them are. The QT is the only series that can do HSS. And the TTL version of the QTII series seem to have disappeared. I mostly went off http://www.godox.com/EN/Products.html

Answer (score 0):

> I currently have a Flashpoint TTL-n ad360.

Actually, you don't. You probably have a Godox AD360II-N, also known as a Flashpoint Streaklight 360 TTL, among many many many other rebrands. The AD360 (Mark I) had no built-in radio transceiver, and did not do TTL as an off-camera slave via an XTR16 or FTR16 receiver (although it can do it on-camera or with a iTTL capable trigger on its foot).

> I would like to remotely control it and perhaps 2 additional speedlights--I guess either Godox or Flashpoint brand--with a single trigger unit on-camera, both in TTL or manual remote control. Which speedlights do you recommend and is there a single trigger that can do all this? How about the new R2 Pro controller?

Any of the current Godox TTL 2.4 GHz transmitters will work (X1T, X2T, Xpro, or Flashpoint R2 Pro II). The X1T is the oldest version with the worst UI. See [this Robert Hall youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qa1_i3Re63M) to get a sense of the differences; Hall's youtube channel also has reviews of the other units so you can see which one you might prefer. But you can also use any of the TTL/HSS Godox speedlights as an on-camera transmitter.

The older XT16 and XT32 transmitters, however, do not do TTL and the XT16 doesn't do HSS.

Godox makes several speedlights, which are basically different models with two versions each: the AA-powered and the li-on powered versions. The li-on versions increase battery capacity by about 2.5x and can speed up a full-power recycle by about 0.25s. Also, the li-on versions have no external battery pack port. Otherwise, the two versions of each model are identical in function and UI. All of them have built in Godox X/Flashpoint R2 radio transceivers. But only the TTL models can be TTL/HSS radio masters. The three models are (from cheapest to most expensive):

- TT600 / V850II (single-pin manual full-sized speedlights)
- TT350 / V350 (TTL mini speedlight)
- TT685 / V860II (TTL full-sized speedlights)
- NA  / V1 (TTL round-headed speedlight [upcoming spring 2019])

Of these, the TT685/V860II models are the most recommended, as they are firmware upgradeable (the manual single-pin flashes are not), and more powerful and fuller-featured than the mini speedlight (the Nikon, Canon, and Sony "flavors" can also do "smart" optical (e.g., CLS/AWS, wireless eTTL, WL) master/slave functions). The minis are typically better for on-camera usage with a smaller mirrorless body, or as a fill flash with radio master capabilities.

> Additionally have an SB700 and some Nissin di700 TTL Nikon flashes if they could me made to work with the Godox 360 and planned new speedlights.

Yes. You can add on the X1R-N receiver onto the foot of each flash and they should be TTL/HSS/remote power slaves in the Godox system.  However, combining 3rd-party-with-3rd-party may have more incompatibilities than combining 3rd-party with OEM, so you may want to do some research on how well Nissin integrates with the X1R-N receiver. And there may still [be some bugs in the communication](https://www.dpreview.com/forums/thread/4235464#forum-post-60513373).

The X1R receivers, however, cannot do cross-brand TTL/HSS/power control, if you choose to fire them from a non-Nikon Godox transmitter on a non-Nikon camera, like the TT685 and V860II can do.

> By the way, I am aware that Flashpoint is actually a private Godox brand. Does Godox also build Yongnuo?

Actually, Flashpoint is an Adorama house brand that is used to cover products made not only by Godox but by other manufacturers as well (although thankfully, they switched from calling the Jinbei stuff Flashpoint as well, and are now rebranding the Jinbei gear as Orlit).

But no, Yongnuo and Godox are two different Chinese companies. They're both rebranded by Neewer, though, along with Triopo and Meike. :)

See also: [Flash Havoc overview of the Godox X system](http://flashhavoc.com/godox-flash-system-overview/), and [a breakdown of the flashes in the system](http://flashhavoc.com/godox-flash-models/).